# Endless printer spooling

Tags: windows-server-2003, printing

I am connecting through remote desktop to a Windows 2003 Server. As soon as I connect I get this on my local machine:

`REMOTE DESKTOP REDIRECTED PRINTER DOC`

for the spool window of **every one** of my local printers. It's cyclical and keeps doing it and doing it.

Is it possible for me to trace where is this coming from? Maybe i can find which port its coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's coming from your MSTSC options. There's an option when you RDP into a server to install your printers on that server. Uncheck it and you should be able to avoid this:

Start-->Run-->MSTSC-->Options-->Local Resources [TAB]-->(Uncheck 'Printers')

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any software like a "PDF writer" or such on the server computer? My gut says to look there first...

Does the problem occur when accessing the server from other client computers, or just the one you're describing here?